# I am new to .NET Core. I am trying to do a POC for user User Login in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

In my case I want to validate the login credential within the same application by using rest controller. But the condition when I click login button the Url should not change and the business logic for the validation should be written in the same application.

My `.cshtml` markup is here:

```
@page
@model RazorApp.Pages.Account.LoginModel
@{
}

<div class="container border" style="padding:20px">
    <form method="post">
        <div class="text-danger" asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <label asp-for="Credential.Username"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <input type="text" asp-for="Credential.Username" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Credential.Username"></div>
        </div><br />
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <label asp-for="Credential.Password"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <input type="password" asp-for="Credential.Password" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Credential.Password"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

My `.cshtml.cs` code is:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace RazorApp.Pages.Account
{
    public class Credential
    {
        [Required]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public Credential Credential { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
                return Page();

            // Verify credentials
            if (Credential.Username == "badruddin" && Credential.Password == "khan@123")
            {
                // create security context
                return Redirect("/Index");
            }

            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

Controller code

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using RazorApp.Pages.Account;

namespace RazorApp
{
    [ApiController]
    public class LoginController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("account/login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync([FromBody] Credential credential)
        {
            if(credential.Username == "badruddin" && credential.Password == "khan@123")
            {
                return Ok(credential);
            }
            else 
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`program.cs` code:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie("MyCookieAuth", options => {
    options.Cookie.Name = "MyCookieAuth";
    });
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Please clarify your question, When submit login form, Do you want the request access  LoginController  instead of `.cshtml.cs` file?

Comment: Yes I want to access Login controller instead of .cshtml.cs file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change your `program.cs` file like:

```
//......

//add this 
builder.Services.AddControllers();

//........

//add this 
app.MapControllers();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Delete your `OnPostAsync` method in `.cshtml.cs` file and change `[FromBody]` to `[FromForm]` in LoginController.

Then the request will access LoginController instead of `.cshtml.cs` file.